# WCF return generic type

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to create an interface and several classes in my WCF Application. For example:
interface ITable.
class Customer : ITable and Employee : ITable

and after this if its possible to create...

```
[OperationContract]
IEnumerable<T> GetTable<T>() where T: ITable, new();
```

...in my service interface.

I've tried once and application got savage.

I want this to simplify my job on client side.
just use Client.GetTable or Client.GetTable to get list of my ITables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble with this is that because it doesn't specify a concrete type, it allows for the possibility that a client invokes the service with a type that implements `ITable` but isn't known to the service. From the client side it will appear to work because the class fits the generic constraint, but then the service can't deserialize it.

You can add one or more `ServiceKnownType` attributes to your service, like this:

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(SomeTable))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(SomeOtherTable))]
[ServiceContract]
public interface IYourService
{
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<T> GetTable<T>() where T: ITable, new();
}
```

That way the service knows what concrete type or types to deserialize into.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I have an additional question. Which attribute does ITable need?

Comment: whenever I use that logic I'm getting this Exception.
**Service cannot be started. System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T]' cannot be exported as a schema type because it is an open generic type. You can only export a generic type if all its generic parameter types are actual types.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.EnsureTypeNotGeneric(Type type)
   at ...**

Answer (score 0):

You can user ServiceKnownType attribute overload that takes a method and the type declaring the method. The method should return IEnumerable.